# componentDidMount() not working for my entire application. This is one of the many components not rendering their results on my page

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';


class Signout extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.signout();
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      Sorry to see you go
    </div>
  }
};

export default connect(null, actions)(Signout);
```

This is not rendering the page to show sorry to see you go. When I click on the link to this component I just get an empty blank page. Several other of my components experience the same thing. Only components that don't need anything from the ComponenDidMount function work on the app.

The component is called from here:

```
import Dashboard from "../views/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
import TagTable from "../views/TagTable/TagTable.jsx";
// @material-ui/icons
import DashboardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import Apps from "@material-ui/icons/Apps";
import SignOut from "../views/Auth/Signout";


var dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: "/tags",
    name: "Tags",
    icon: Apps,
    component: TagTable
  },

  {
    path: "/logout",
    name: "Logout",
    icon: Apps,
    component: SignOut
  },

  { redirect: true, path: "/", pathTo: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard" }
];
export default dashRoutes;
```

The action call is as follows:

```
export const signout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');

  return {
    type: AUTH_USER,
    payload: ''
  };
}
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: Would you provide how `signout` is implemented? and the component that shows the link that triggers the action creator?

Comment: No errors in the console its extremely strange.

Comment: Let me know if I'm missing anything you need to review.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
 return (
    <div>
       Sorry to see you go
    </div>
)
```

Enclose your divs inside parenthesis.

Comment: Didn't work but I got a warning:

./src/views/Auth/Signout.js
  Line 13:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 13:  Unreachable code                                                       no-unreachable

Answer (score 0):

Hum! Put the text inside h1 tags or p tags instead of divs.